# undefined reference while compile libgphoto2/examples

Tags: libgphoto2

My question is about libgphoto2 in gphoto2 from https://github.com/gphoto/libgphoto2/tree/master/examples

I try to compile "libgphoto2/examples/lunkwill-canon-capture.c" (basically all .c file in libgphoto2/example show same error)

gcc -Wall -o TESTOUTPUT -lgphoto2 sample-trigger-capture.c (as libgphoto2 manual suggest)

I got error

```
/tmp/ccg65O2b.o: In function `wait_event_and_download':
sample-trigger-capture.c:(.text+0xad): undefined reference to `gp_camera_wait_for_event'
sample-trigger-capture.c:(.text+0x371): undefined reference to `gp_camera_file_read'
sample-trigger-capture.c:(.text+0x57b): undefined reference to `gp_camera_file_delete'
/tmp/ccg65O2b.o: In function `main':
sample-trigger-capture.c:(.text+0x607): undefined reference to `sample_create_context'
sample-trigger-capture.c:(.text+0x64c): undefined reference to `gp_log_add_func'
sample-trigger-capture.c:(.text+0x658): undefined reference to `gp_camera_new'
sample-trigger-capture.c:(.text+0x66b): undefined reference to `gp_camera_init'
sample-trigger-capture.c:(.text+0x6db): undefined reference to `gp_camera_trigger_capture'
sample-trigger-capture.c:(.text+0x799): undefined reference to `gp_camera_exit'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What did I do wrong?
best regards

Answer (score 0):

trying this command

gcc -Wall -o TESTOUTPUT sample-trigger-capture.c -lgphoto2 -lgphoto2_port

you missed to include 'gphoto2_port'